# Delete row from database through Servlet

Tags: html, servlets, jdbc

I had a problem in my servlet regarding deleting record from my database.
Please look over my servlet code and please do correct me. Thank you in advance
DeleteRow servlet is working perfectly right when a single ID is given manually.
Scenario is:

ManageSinger.java servlet displays the records in database along with a       "Delete" hyperLink in every row. But problem is whenever i try to press delete button.. it receives a null value for ID in deleterow.java servlet ..
Please guide me from here how can only that corresponding ID can be pass to another servlet.

**ManageSinger.java**

```
package com.ea.servlet;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class ManageSinger extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException, ServletException {
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
    res.setContentType("text/html");
    out.println("<html><body>");
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EATWO","root","");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from singerdetails");
        out.println("<form method = \"post\">");
        out.println("<table border=1 width=50% height=50%>");
        out.println("<tr><th align=\"center\">Singer Name</th><th align=\"center\">StageName</th><th align=\"center\">Language</th><th></th><tr>");
        while (rs.next()) {
            String singername = rs.getString("singername");
            String stagename = rs.getString("stagename");
            String language = rs.getString("language"); 
            String id = rs.getString("userID");
            HttpSession session = req.getSession(true); 
            session.setAttribute("userID",id);
            out.println("<tr><td align=\"center\">" + singername + "</td><td align=\"center\">" + stagename + "</td><td align=\"center\">" + language + "</td><td align=\"center\"><a href = \"./deleterow\">Delete</a></td></tr>");
        }
        out.println("</table>");
        out.println("</form");
        out.println("</body></html>");
        con.close();
       }
        catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{

    }
}
}
```

**DeleteRow.java**

```
package com.ea.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.jws.Oneway;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


public class DeleteRow extends HttpServlet
{
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
throws IOException, ServletException
{
res.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
Connection con;
PreparedStatement st;
ResultSet rs;
try
{ 
HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
String id = (String) session.getAttribute("id");
System.out.println(id);
con =        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EATWO","root","");
st= con.prepareStatement("delete from singerdetails where userID = ?");
st.setString(1, id);
st.executeUpdate();
int i = st.executeUpdate();
if(i!=0)
pw.println("Deleting row...");
else if (i==0)
{
pw.println("<br>Row has been deleted successfully.");
}
}
catch(SQLException sx)
{
pw.println(sx);
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException cx)
{
pw.println(cx);
}   
}
}
```

Comment: Here you should say String id = (String) session.getAttribute("userID"); instead of (String) session.getAttribute("id") in DeleteRow.java

Comment: ThankYou!!! It Worked. Rows are deleting. But not Correctly. When i click on delete for 5th row. Last row gets deleted.. @AvinashReddy Can you look once again

Comment: That means last userID is passing instead of required userID. please do help me out from here

Comment: In ManageSinger.java while u are doing this out.println("<tr><td align=\"center\">" + singername + "</td><td align=\"center\">" + stagename + "</td><td align=\"center\">" + language + "</td><td align=\"center\"><a href = \"./deleterow\">Delete</a></td></tr>"); please try to add userid and check whether the userid is coming for all the rows that you are deleting

Comment: @AvinashReddy Probably you could make your comment as answer.

Comment: @learningloop added my answer as suggested by you

Comment: @AvinashReddy yes, their respective userID is coming for all rows

Comment: @ChandraKishore Then in that case it should delete properly right. It should not delete as said by you.

Comment: @AvinashReddy  i wish i can show you screenshots for better understanding.
But i dont know what went wrong but last row gets deleted whenever i click delete irrespective of their userID's

Comment: In ManageSinger servlet., i tried to printout the userID's., it printed all the userID's available., so it is taking last userID and passing over to deleterow servlet. Thats the problem. I am not getting any idea how to overcome this sort of problem. Just please do check it once again. Thankyou in Advance

Comment: @ChandraKishore : I think this is the problem session.setAttribute("userID",id); Since you are setting the value in the while loop, the setting of userId is getting overridden and only the last row value is being set in the id. Please check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your current `ManageSinger.java` only the last `userID` gets set in session, which is why the last `userID` gets deleted. In `ManageSinger.java` instead of setting the userID as session attribute you can set it as url parameter for each record.

Following lists the changes:

```
//HttpSession session = req.getSession(true); 
//session.setAttribute("userID",id);
out.println("<tr><td align=\"center\">" + singername + "</td><td align=\"center\">" + stagename + "</td><td align=\"center\">" + language + "</td><td align=\"center\"><a href = \"./deleterow?userID="+id+"\">Delete</a></td></tr>");
```

In `DeleteRow.java` instead of getting the `userID` from session, you can get it from the url as following:

```
//HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
//String id = (String) session.getAttribute("id");
String id = req.getParameter("userID").toString();
```

Comment: Thats Great!!! #learningloop @AvinashReddy 
That Worked!!!!   ThankYou Veryyyy Much... +1 ThankYou Both of you

Answer (score 2):

In DeleteRow.java say you should do `String id = (String) session.getAttribute("userID")`; instead of `(String) session.getAttribute("id")` .In ManageSinger.java you are setting the attribute as follows `session.setAttribute("userID",id)`;

Comment: Thats Great!!! #learningloop @AvinashReddy That Worked!!!! ThankYou Veryyyy Much... +1 ThankYou Both of you